# ISO C++ forbids member initialization within a struct

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, compiler-errors, in-class-initialization

I'm writing an emulator and decided to control input/output emulation within a struct:

```
struct callbacks
{
short LastFrequency = 9000;
 int *MMIO_RANGE1;
 short Cycle_LN = 65535 / LastFrequency;
 const char *STATUS_FLAGS[] =
 {
   "ACK",
   "NO_VIB",
   "DATA",
   "BYTEPACK",
   "WORDPACK"
 };
}
```

This code above looks fine to me and seems to obey all of the rules ... but I get the error message as stated in the title above. I searched around and people say that the error means different things ... but what is it?

The problem is pointed towards "LastFrequency".

Comment: I am using C++11; the error is coming right from that.

Comment: Also you are missing a `;` at the end of `callbacks`'s definition

Comment: @40two Adding it makes no difference; still the same error.

Comment: Perhaps it's time to upgrade your compiler. That's my next best guess.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Please post the error output.

Comment: I'm using the latest release: MinGW; Windows version.

Comment: Latest release of what? GCC? Clang? MSVC? TC++ (please no)?

Comment: Get rid of the zero size array - make it `const char *STATUS_FLAGS[5]`

Comment: or use `static constexpr` and compile in C++11 mode

Comment: Better of use `std::vector<std::string>`

Comment: @DieterLücking Doesn't affect the error.

Comment: @40two, `std::array<std::string, 5>`*

Comment: `LastFrequency` is a simple member of this struct. Use a constructor initializer list to initialize it.

Comment: None of the suggestions help the Wfatal-error: "ISO C++ forbids member initialization of 'LastFrequency'".

Comment: @chris I agree ;), it's more pedantic than my solution.

Comment: My guess of time for a compiler upgrade is looking more and more likely. This feature was introduced in GCC 4.7.

Comment: My compiler is 4.6-4.7.

Comment: Does `g++ --version` report both 4.6 and 4.7? Make sure you're passing the `-std=c++11` switch to the compiler. And when you get a chance, can you please fix that ALLCAPS USERNAME? It's kinda annoying. Thanks.

Comment: @TemplateRex IMHO If an embedded device can't make use of `std::array` or `std::vector` then C++ isn't an option (maybe assembly).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things: add a `5` and a `;`

Also: make sure to compile with `-std=c++11` (or `-std=c++0x` for older g++ versions, or the equivalent options for your compiler of choice), because **in-class initializers are a C++11 feature**.

**BIG WARNING:** this code is [**NOT supported by gcc 4.6**](http://goo.gl/77tqkU) and requires gcc >= 4.7.3

```
struct callbacks
{
short LastFrequency = 9000;
 int *MMIO_RANGE1;
 short Cycle_LN = 65535 / LastFrequency;
 const char *STATUS_FLAGS[5] = // <-- 5 here
 {
   "ACK",
   "NO_VIB",
   "DATA",
   "BYTEPACK",
   "WORDPACK"
 };
}; // <-- ; here

int main() 
{

}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec67c59b11eed13a).

Comment: I already stated that I did that and still get the same error.

Comment: then your compiler dont support full c++11

Comment: Yes, C++11 GCC 4.6-4.7 MinGW for Windows binaries.